# How to embed your own videos?

Tags: html, css, video

I'm really bad at explaining things so if you have any questions, feel free to ask! 
I basically want to put my own videos on my webpage, i've tried doing so with the youtube videos but unfortunately it's saying VEVO disallow it because of copyright. Is there any way of putting my video onto my webpage? Just like you do with putting your own images on your website. The videos I want are currently on my desktop I just want to put videos onto my webpage. Anyone know the syntax? Thanks in advance!:)

Also, can someone tell me the best format for videos that is supported by most internet browsers?

Comment: @San I've not tried anything, I've checked everywhere but can't find the syntax for it:/

Comment: what format videos you want to run? flv or mp4?

Comment: What do you mean by syntax? Like `<video>` or?

Comment: @San I was hoping MP4, but I'm not sure which browsers don't support it

Comment: @Vallentin I mean like the actual code to use in order to get it working, if you know what I mean?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=mp4, not all browsers support mp4. But you can just do `<video src="yourvideo.mp4"></video>`

Comment: @putvande Thank you! Can you please put this as an answer so I can mark it? Thanks

Comment: there are many free players available online here is one http://flvplayer.com/free-flv-player/ plays few formats including mp4 and flv

Comment: @Putvande Do I have to add some code for a play button and pause etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload your MP4 to your server and use the following sintax:

```
<video src="yourvideo.mp4" controls></video>
```

But as mentioned, MP4 is not a type that is supported in all browsers, so it would be good to use different formats like WEBM and OGG / OGV. 
If you have more video types you can use

```
<video controls>
    <source src="yourvideo.mp4" />
    <source src="yourvideo.webm" />
    <source src="yourvideo.ogv" />
</video>
```

You can find out on http://caniuse.com/#search=mp4 what browser supports MP4.
Add the attribute `controls` to add play button etc.